# Rbenv not working

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I installed ruby 2.0 into ~/.rbenv/versions last and now nothing but that is available

$ rbenv versions

```
system
*ruby-1.9.3-p392 (set by /apps/test_app/.ruby-version)
ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

$ ruby -v

```
ruby 2.0.0.p0
```

$ env | grep PATH

```
PATH=/home/cbron/.rbenv/shims:/home/cbron/.rbenv/bin
```

$cat ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

$rbenv global

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

$rbenv local

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

$rbenv shell

```
rbenv: no shell-specific version configured
```

edit: now set the shell, still nothing.

$rbenv shell

```
ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

ruby -v   still getting

```
ruby 2.0.0p0
```

I already sourced my bash_profile, even restarted the computer.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue using zsh and this fixed it:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv
$ echo 'source $HOME/.zshenv' >> ~/.zshrc
$ exec $SHELL
```

So basically moving the lines from profile to env!

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [rbenv readme](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-shell):

> #### rbenv shell
>
> Sets a shell-specific Ruby version by setting the `RBENV_VERSION`
> environment variable in your shell. This version overrides
> application-specific versions and the global version.
>
> ```
> $ rbenv shell jruby-1.7.1
> ```
>
> When run without a version number, `rbenv shell` reports the current
> value of `RBENV_VERSION`. You can also unset the shell version:
>
> ```
> $ rbenv shell --unset
> ```
>
> Note that you'll need rbenv's shell integration enabled (step 3 of the
> installation instructions) in order to use this command. If you prefer
> not to use shell integration, you may simply set the `RBENV_VERSION`
> variable yourself:
>
> ```
> $ export RBENV_VERSION=jruby-1.7.1
> ```

So in order to use it you need to specify the ruby version as `rbenv shell` argument (f.e. `rbenv shell 2.0.0.p0`, or set `RBENV_VERSION` (f.e. `export RBENV_VERSION=2.0.0.p0`)

Comment: Yea I get that, but if I'm in a directory that specifies the ruby version, wouldn't it pick that up ? Or do I have to specify a different shell version ?

Comment: If you are in a directory with a `.ruby-version` file you should use `rbenv local`, not `rbenv shell`, which sets a per-shell ruby version, and doesn't belong with the directory configuration

Comment: `rbenv local`: ruby-1.9.3-p392. I tried setting the shell too and its still stuck on ruby 2.0.

Comment: uhmmmm copy and paste this in your shell: `source ~/.bash_profile && rbenv shell 1.9.3-p392 && ruby -v` what is the output?

Comment: `ruby 2.0.0p0`. Does it matter that I had ruby installed previously before I installed rbenv and the two ruby versions inside of it ?

Comment: the system ruby?, no it doesn't... it could be a problem if there are traces of RVM... aren't there?

Comment: It was on there before but its fully uninstalled. Nothing in my bash files, path, home dir, etc. I did `grep -r "rvm" ~/*` and all it found was log files.

Comment: Did you guys ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** just reinstall rbenv, unless you are as stubborn as me...

---

I had messed up permissions in the `.rbenv` folder, so the [shims](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-shims) weren't loading because they didn't have *execute permissions*

```
chmod u+x ~/.rbenv/shims/*
```

---

### Disclaimer

I had deeper permissions problems, **rbenv** wasn't even working, so I did other `chmod u+x ...` previously

```
chmod u+x ~/.rbenv/libexec/*
chmod u+x ~/.rbenv/**/bin/*
```

*Probably easier and safer to just reinstall **rbenv**. But this was fun!*